# what key axioms are behind calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, axioms

what key axioms make calculus correct? I know there are axioms for real numbers, are there any other important axioms behind calculus?

Comment: Once you have the real numbers, the res of calculus is definitions and theorems about them,  so there are no more axioms.

Comment: Adding to the previous comment: and the specific property of the set of real numbers which is crucial is the completeness axiom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Axiom choice (AC) is possibly the most important axiom behind calculus, in general.

Many results in calculus are equivalent to it (or its weaker form).

One example where we use it is the characterisation of real continous functions with sequences (but hundreds of examples).